# Is there an iOS mail scheme url for Google's Inbox?

Tags: ios, email, nsurl, url-scheme

If you want to check if your user has Gmail (so you can switch to Gmail to send an email) you can see if they can open "googlegmail:///co?to="

Is there something equivalent for Google's new app, Google Inbox?

I tried "googleinbox:///" but it didn't work.

Is there a place where you can find these links?
Tried: http://handleopenurl.com/, but doesn't even have Gmail (EDIT now this site is dead.)

Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to open the Gmail app in a specific account?

Comment: Note for future finders of this question: The Google Inbox app no longer exists.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the goolge inbox app no longer exists

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Info.plist in the Inbox app lists 4 URL Schemes it will respond to:

```
inbox-gmail
inbox-gmail-x-callback
com.google.sso.296495646338-v31uuqp2kboh7qfi8jh5oga1lk1lb5sj
com.google.sso.294296358152-6s4pqed0qa6sk3m3k2pcmsu2jidh8n5u
```

The last two are most likely for single sign on callbacks, and the second is probably used for returning to Inbox after Inbox itself does an [UIAppliaction openURL:] to another Google app (e.g. Google Maps). I've tested "inbox-gmail" and it does open the Inbox app.

To open Inbox and compose an email you use the same url as gmail, but without the triple forward slash:

```
googlegmail:///co?to={email}&subject={subject}&body={body}

inbox-gmail://co?to={email}&subject={subject}&body={body}
```

Here's how you can access Info.plist for Inbox or any other app on the App store

1. Download the app in iTunes on your Mac
2. Go to the "My Apps" tab, right click on the app and choose "Show in Finder"
3. Right click on the app file and "Open with" -> "Archive Utility"
4. Open the extracted folder. Open "Payload" folder.
5. Right click on application and choose "Show Package Contents"
6. You've now got access to the Info.plist for the app and all the other resources: image, sounds, .strings, etc.

Comment: If you're using iOS 9 you need to whitelist the URL Scheme before call `canOpenURL:` method.