# Where to find tthe documentation to use googlemail commands on mobile device?

Tags: ios, mobile, gmail

I'm looking for the documentation that cover this kind of links :

`googlemail:///co?to=email`

(An example in this thread : [Is there an iOS mail scheme url for Google's Inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655978/is-there-an-ios-mail-scheme-url-for-googles-inbox))

I would like to make a search for specific mail executing a command using gmail app on my mobile device  (IOS)

Something like that : `googlemail:///search?messageId=foo`

But I'm not enabled to find the rigth documentation.

Thx.